# Browser displays entity name instead of symbol

Tags: asp.net, html, html-entities

I have a grid (unfortunately third-party) and I populate it with data. Data is encoded like:

```
&lt;test&gt;
```

When page is displayed I still see

```
&lt;test&gt;
```

instead of

```
<test>
```

Any ideas why? Or even how it's possible to display `&lt;` ad `<` in browser?

Comment: considering it's displaying `&lt;` as plain text, have you tried `<`?

Comment: You'd need to tell asp.net to not escape HTML entities. Otherwise `&lt;` is rendered as `&amp;lt;` and thus displayed as `&lt;`. Or, better, you should not have escaped data in first place.

Comment: Does the third party control automatically encode the HTML? You should be able to check this by viewing the HTML source. If it does you would see something like `&amp;lt;test&amp;gt;`.

Comment: Thanks :) Indeed, data was encoded twice! Draw up an answer so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that control did html encoding behind the scenes, and printed text was :

> &amp;lt;test&amp;gt;